# How to back-up and restore site settings in Core FTP Pro?

Tags: backup, ftp

I'm using Core FTP Pro V2.1. I have set a lot of website FTP credentials on my instance. I'm going to reinstall my Windows, so I'm wondering: how I can back up all those settings and restore them on the newly installed Windows?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For those who have the same problem, I found this solution:

**For backing up** go to "Site Manager" (Site Menu -> Site Manager), right-click on area and in the context-menu chose "Export".

This way you can save your "Site setting credentials" on your Hard disk.

**For Restoring** do the same but in the context-menu chose "Import".

Comment: Yeah, sounds good only the program exports the file without an extension,
and thus isnt able to import them, either. No workee at allee.

Comment: Despite the fact that there is no file extension, it doesn't matter. The export/import worked perfectly for me, took 1 minute! (using the free version Core FTP LE, version 2.2